# How to download newer files using WinSCP and save them to two local folders?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ftp, winscp

I have file in a folder (`ftp_region`) whose contents is similar to data in  my FTP.

How to download newer files from my FTP and save them to two local folders (`ftp_region` and other folder)

For now, I use this:

```
open "my ftp address"
get -neweronly "..." "..."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this with a plain WinSCP scripting.

You better use the [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library). It allows you to process the downloaded files.

An example code in [PowerShell](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell):

```ps
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

# Setup session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Ftp
    HostName = "ftp.example.com"
    UserName = "user"
    Password = "password"
}

Write-Host "Connecting..."
$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
# $session.SessionLogPath = "C:\path\to\log\sync.log"
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

$remotePath = "/remote/path"
$localPathPrimary = "C:\backup\primary"
$localPathSecondary = "C:\backup\secondary"

Write-Host "Synchronizing..."
$result =
    $session.SynchronizeDirectories(
        [WinSCP.SynchronizationMode]::Local, $localPathPrimary, $remotePath,
        $False)
$result.Check()

Write-Host "Copying downloaded files to secondary backup..."
foreach ($download in $result.Downloads)
{
    $filename = (Split-Path -Leaf $download.Destination)
    $localFilePathSecondary = (Join-Path $localPathSecondary $filename)
    Copy-Item $download.Destination $localFilePathSecondary
    Write-Host "File $filename archived to both folders."
}
```

---

The code is based on an official example [Deleting remote files after successful remote to local synchronization](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_delete_after_successful_download).